# android - how to recover keystore file

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I have lost my `keystore` file now i need to update my app on play store is there any way to get my `keystore` file i have my old `signed apk` please any answer will be appreciated

Comment: Restore your keystore from your backup. You *are* backing up your development machine, right?

Comment: the only option is unpublishing your old old app and uploading it with new package name, signed with new keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot recover a lost keystore.

The signature on your existing APK is just a signature- you cannot reproduce the signature without the key that generated the signature.

Google does not store, keep track of, or ever have access to your keystore. It is completely on the developer to manage the keystore.

Your options are:

- Find the keystore
- Generate a new keystore and re-upload your application as a new application. You will be starting completely fresh with this option.

Answer (score 10):

Access:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs?hl=en

and mark the options like below:

[image]