# How to update an android app If you lose keystore file?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, code-signing

I am new to the Android ecosystem. To give you a more context about my problem, here are some facts.

- I've received access to a google developer team, who released time
  ago an application.
- Now, I want to release a new version of that.
- The new version is a completely new app. Have the same functionality, but is developed by somebody else.
- All setup is made correctly, including the bundle id of the app.

Now, the problem is related to APK signing. From what I understand I should use something named Keystore file to sign the app in order to be able to update the current app.

The problem here, is that I can't obtain this file, because the previous developer doesn't have it anymore.

[image]

My question is, what can I do in this case. Releasing as a new app is not an option.

Verry important, the last developer doesn't have the option to let google to manage the signing keys.

Thank you for your help!

---

I founded a related question, but the answers are old, so maybe, since then google may come up with a backup plan to recover this.

[android - how to recover Keystore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105053/android-how-to-recover-keystore-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android - how to recover keystore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105053/android-how-to-recover-keystore-file)

Comment: I've already found that question, but I hope that in 3 years something has changed, and maybe  there is a solution to recover/ replace that file.

Comment: Not really. If you're signing the app yourself rather than letting Google Play do it, then it's your responsibility to keep the keystore safe (or in this case the customer's and prior developer's responsibility). If they've lost the key then you're out of luck.

Comment: This doesn't sound fun at all.  Right now I'm in denial state... There should be a solution. I refuse to accept that google didn't give an option to recover such a such important key...

Comment: They can't recover it, Google have never seen . They can't allow a new one either as all the devices out there would consider it a mismatch.

Comment: Thank you Michael & MattiasIsegranBergander for your responses. I've started taking into account some alternative solutions, but none of them are good enough. All can lead to losing too many users. So, I'll do my best to retrieve the old certificates from the previous developer... Hope to get somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Following are the steps to generate new keystores with the help of Google Play Console.**

**Step 1.**
First of all Goto this Link [https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs]
in which they are asking about

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address
- Developer Name
- Developer Account ID
- Location
- App Name
- App Package name

and select your issues
in the context of mine i select(I have a key or keystore related issue-->I have an upload key-related issue-->I lost my upload key).

After Submitting our request they Send us Email in which they are telling that we have to do two steps-

**In first step** we open our command window in a specific folder and copy this below command and hit enter

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

after hitting enter we have to put key and password.
it will generate .jks file

**In Second step** copy second query and paste it into command window and hit enter
       now it will generate a .pem

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

**Step 3.**

Now in the reply of email that Google Help Center send us attach .pem file

**Step 4.**

Now they register our new generated key but it will give some days to be valid.

**Step 5.**

Now Create signed apk with that key and upload to play store.

Comment: This is valid only if you have enabled signing managed by google. Otherwise, the only solution is the one presented by Alexander Hoffmann.

Comment: The new link to ask Google is https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp?visit_id=637826024375299390-3686495906&rd=1#

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

You'll need to release a new app with a new play store entry.

When you sign your APKs yourself, as soon as you upload **any** signed APK to the Google Play Store, all further uploads will require the same signing key.

This is also true if you upload an APK to the internal, alpha or beta test channels even without publishing the tests. Just the upload of the first APK will lock you in.

Comment: How can I update the keystore file in android. It shows my key is too weak

Comment: @sejn Did you find a solution for your query?

Comment: I have created a new key for the new apps and used the existing weak key for already available apps.