# Error showcase on android app new version release

Tags: android

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 33:6D:60:7D:34:53:FF:1A:C6:5B:5D:A5:5C:CC:2C:34:A8:58:52:4C ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 23:AE:1D:5F:DA:EC:73:49:E0:1F:AD:F2:0F:A3:17:C3:42:27:79:CC ]

Comment: You need to sign your app with the correct keystore in order to update it? [How to update an android app If you lose keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692560/how-to-update-an-android-app-if-you-lose-keystore-file)

Comment: @hupen paija, can you be more specific on what you're trying to do and the specific error you're getting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105080/9850623

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to upload an update to the google play store, it **must** be signed ( Build > Generate Signed Apk/Bundle ) with the same key as the application currently online

Answer (score 0):

Its probably look like you generate a signed apk with new key, then only this issue has came, you have to use the same key which you have used first time to generate signed apk to upload on play store.

If you lost your signed apk key of play store then its not possible to update it again.

Only one solution is that

**You'll need to release a new app with a new play store entry.**

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, thank you very much buddy. Yeah, the I had done that for sure. So, for new release, should it have different package name?